# Build corona project for google-play-store

Tags: android, coronasdk

I build my app for android using corona simulator and then i sign that apk with [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) process but when i try to publish it on Google play i got this

"1. You uploaded a debuggable APK. For security reasons you need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play. Learn more about debuggable APKs.

2. Your APK has been signed with multiple certificates. Please only sign it with one certificate and upload it again.
3. Your APK needs to have the package name com.gmail.mustafacorona.tnt.
4. You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 1"

Comment: You are unlikely to get an answer for this question. StackOverflow helps solving concrete problems by giving an answer to the cause or a solution. In this case you already have the answer to the cause and just need to handle them one by one.

Answer (score 1):

I made a great forum topic over here regarding this topic:

http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/7111-signing-android-applications-in-3-easy-steps/

That should help you out.  Basically you create your keystore, and build your application using the keystore.

Comment: i have create a keystore and signed apk with that but now i am facing error 1 and error 4, i can take care of error 4 but what is about the error 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the error 1 is occurring because your "build.settings" file contains the following line:

```
neverStripDebugInfo = true
```

Try changing it to:

```
neverStripDebugInfo = false
```